# Saving Dc opf result into a file, matpower, matlab, power flow

Tags: matlab, matpower

I want to ask help for saving my results into a file in matpower. I have rundcopf for 24 bus[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTHtI.png). I was instructed to extract the data is to go to the result. File for a better way. Also I need to stress the system, I need to increase loading by 1.5x or 2x and then check. Please help me. Thank you!

I want to ask help for saving my results into a file in matpower

Comment: what version of MATPOWER do you use? 8?